# Global Variables alternative

Tags: javascript, global-variables

I want to create an array that is accessible to all the .js files.  This array must also be updateable, and the updated changes must be reflected in all the other files using that array.

I have read that using a GLOBAL variable is not a good method, but what is the alternative?

```
//file 1 which contains my global variable
var mySharedArray = ['helo']; 
module.exports = {
mySharedArray: mySharedArray,
get: function(){
    console.log(mySharedArray);
} 
}    

//file 2 where i am pushing new-data 
router.get('/workerequestest',function(req,res){
queue.push("moreData");
require('../config/globalQueue').get();
require('../config/startWorkerQueue');
res.send(200,'message recieved');
});

//file 3 where i am checking the updated values
var interval = setInterval(function() {
var Queue = require('../config/globalQueue').mySharedArray;
require('../config/globalQueue').get();
}, 10000,'hello' ,'checking for New processes');
```

Comment: a module that gets required where said variable is needed.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with node.js.

Comment: thanks for being quick. can you be little more specific.. may be explain with an example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Proper modularity in node.js does not use actual globals as that makes actually taking advantage of reusable modules more complicated and makes for possible conflicts with other globals.

One design pattern that can be used instead is to put the shared data in its own module and then just `require()` in that module wherever needed.

```
// shared-data.js
var mySharedArray = [...];

module.exports = {
    mySharedArray: mySharedArray
}
```

Then, in each module that wants to have access to that array, you can do this:

```
// someothermodule.js

var sharedArray = require('./shared-data.js').mySharedArray;


// this modification will change the main array and will be seen by
// all modules that are sharing it
sharedArray.push("moreData");
```

This works because when arrays are assigned in Javascript, they are not copied, but instead a pointer to the original array is shared.  So, any modifications to the assigned value is just pointing at the original object and thus changes the original array.  Thus, all modules would have access to the same original array.

---

I just tested this concept in my own three files and it works fine.  Here are my three files:

**Server File:**

```
// shared-server.js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(80);
var shared = require('./shared-var');
require('./shared-interval.js')

var cntr = 0;

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get("/test", function(req, res) {
    shared.mySharedArray.push(++cntr);
    shared.get();
    res.send(200,'message received');
});
```

**Shared Variable File:**

```
//shared-var.js
var mySharedArray = ['helo']; 
module.exports = {
    mySharedArray: mySharedArray,
    get: function(){
        console.log(mySharedArray);
    } 
}
```

**Interval File:**

```
//shared-interval.js
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    require('./shared-var').get();
}, 1000);
```

When I run this, it outputs the value of `mySharedArray` every second.  Each time I go to http://localhost/test with my browser, it adds a new value to `mySharedArray` and I see that in the console.  This is the behavior I would expect.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @jfriend00 . But can you explain with an example.

Comment: @Furious - there's an example in my answer now.

Comment: i tried using the above example.it didnt worked.I used three files 1. to store the data 2. to update the array & 3 . to get the updated array.  But i was not able to get the updated values in the 3rd file. the updated values were only shown in the third file.

Comment: @Furious - As long as you are modifying the array object and not assigning a new array to it, it will work just fine.  For me to help you with your implementation, you would have to show the actual code you tried (by editing it into your question) so I could see what you're doing differently.

Comment: I have edited the question with the example i am trying .Please have a look where i am wrong.

Comment: @Furious - what's the variable `queue` in `queue.push("moreData");`?  You don't show what that is.  I also don't understand where you think there is a problem?

Comment: var queue = require('../config/globalQueue').mySharedArray; is the file where global variable is stored.

Comment: As you can see i am checking the value of the queue every 10 sec . when i push the value to the queue from file 2. I don't see any update in the value of the queue in file3

Comment: @Furious - I just tested the concept in my own three files and it works for me.  I've included the contents of my three files at the end of my answer.

Comment: jfriend00.Thanks for the help. it is working file.One more doubt. can we have a queue shared by multiple processes not just multiple file??

Comment: @Furious - You cannot directly share a variable between multiple processes.  There are multiple possible approaches to solve that type of issue.  One process could hold the queue and the others could send it http requests to query the queue.  Or, you could use an in-memory store like redis to hold the queue and have each process access the queue via redis.  When sharing data between processes, the data will have to be normalized into something like JSON too since you can't pass live Javascript objects between processes.

Answer (score 1):

You could put them in a separate module that gets required in whatever module you need it in, else you could use a seperate storage service such as [redis](http://redis.io/) or [memcached](http://memcached.org/) to store your array of data.